# How to get extra data from pending intent inside the library module?

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, android-pendingintent

I am creating a library to be embedded in the projects. On receiving the push notification, when the user clicks on the notification, extra data is received via intent in onNewIntent at the app level but i want this data inside the library module. How can we achieve it?

Inside the library module i am trying to get the data using the app level activity's weak reference.

The extras i am getting is null. However, i am able to get the intent value in onNewIntent of the MainActivity.

e.g.

```
 private fun checkNotificationClick(context: WeakReference<Activity>?) {

    val activity = context!!.get()
    val extras = activity?.intent?.extras
    if (extras != null) {
        if (extras.getString("message_id") != null) { 
            val messageId = extras.getString("message_id")
        }
    }
  }
```

The extra data from the intent is expected but it is coming null.

Comment: Hey, did you try making an abstract or just an open class that extends `Activity` then make your library user inherit that abstract?

Comment: @Hohenheim It's all dependent on the user how he keeps the class properties. The library can't be made dependent on such criteria. I just have the context available of the Activity created by the user at app level.

Answer (score 0):

Inform the user of your library that he has to call a method in your library from `onNewIntent()` that passes the `Intent` to the library. This information is not stored (by default) anywhere that you could get it from.

The user should also call that method from `onCreate()` with the original `Intent` as well, for the sake of consistency.